# Customising nivo slider jQuery

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I need to slightly amend this script;

```
  //Changed this
    $('.nivo-controlNav a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass('active');
      //To this
    $('.nivo-controlNav a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass(function (p) {return 'active-'+ (p+1);});

    $('.nivo-controlNav a', slider).live('click', function(){
        if(vars.running) return false;
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = '';
        slider.css('background','url("'+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +'") no-repeat');
        vars.currentSlide = $(this).attr('rel') - 1;
        nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'control');
    });
}
```

Which adds -(current count) E.G. active-1, active-2 ect.

The problem is whenever I try to amend the removal of the class I can not seem to get it to work?

Sorry pretty new to jQuery, any help would be great.

Many Thanks

---- edit ----

I have got the first active link working fine with

```
$('.nivo-controlNav a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass(function (p) {return 'active-'+ (p+1);});
```

its just this

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
```

is obviously not removing the class because it is now active-1 ect... just wondering if I am able to remove the class?

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind that is because it references the class 'active' in various parts of the script and in the CSS

Try:

```
$('.nivo-controlNav a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass(function (p) {return 'active active-'+ (p+1);});
```

It will keep the active class, but also add your active-number. Beware, on multiple iterations of the slides, it will continue to add active-number so an element can start getting many active-number classes assigned: like active-1 active-4 active-12.

Is there a reason to add the number to the active item? You need to write css or JS to support the active-number from 0 to really high numbers.

Comment: I have a maximum of 6 images on the slider, the reasoning behind this is because each of the images a different button and active colour. the code above would remove a class 'active' but because I have added a dynamic number p+1 I can not get this bit if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false; to recognise what the actual active link is

Comment: Hmmm, I went to 'Coin Slider' because I was having customization issues with Nivo. I don't know what to tell you, other than try to build it in the html or image, not the Javascript...